# В положении. В интересном положении

Tags: фразеология, значение-слов, синонимы

*П.А. Вяземский свободно употреблял выражения и «в интересном положении», и «беременна».*

Как объяснить бытование этого оборота? Ведь он составлен из слов, которые, казалось бы, «ни о чём»?

Если не употреблять *беременна*, *брюхата*, *понесла* и т. п. вперемешку с «в положении», то как по одному этому фразеологизму понятно было бы, о чём речь? Не в том ли интерес положения, что не ясно до самого разрешения от бремени кто появится на свет?

Answer (score 5):

***В интересном положении*** - эвфемизм, более изящный по сравнению с нейтральным (но воспринимающимся как тяжеловатое, простоватое) словом "беременна". Бремя - тяжесть, груз.

Сфера употребления того и другого выражения различна.

***Беременна*** говорят о любой женщине, без оттенка чувства (в медицине, например); ***в интересном положении*** - фраза о ком-то, к кому испытывают интерес, какие-то чувства, кто находится рядом, неподалёку, кому могут передать слова говорящего и т. д. Это эмоционально окрашенная фраза.

Comment: Спасибо, наблюдение интересное, хотя во всяком иносказании изящества по определению больше, чем в оригинале. Но (касательно вопроса) не о том хотелось бы узнать. Пожалуй, добавлю несколько слов к вопросу.

Comment: -Тем более, что она сейчас в таком положении... - В каком положении?- Ну, в интересном, понимаете? - Беременна.что ли? - Ну да, да... Может быть, примерно так родилось это выражение?

Comment: Или наоборот. Грузна, непраздна, тяжела, чревата! Что мямлить-то? Говорите прямо, что — в интересном положении.

Answer (score 1):

Выражение, скорее всего, заимствовано из французского. По крайней мере, во французском языке есть [position intéressante](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/position_int%C3%A9ressante)/situation_intéressante, означающее в точности то же самое.  В английском языке тоже есть выражение interesting condition с тем же значением (ныне устаревшее). Согласно викисловарю, interesting condition употреблялось с середины XVIII века. В итальянском есть posizione interessante, в немецком не нашёл.

Так что собеседники Вяземского всё прекрасно понимали, потому что знали французский язык.

А почему это выражение понимали французы, англичане и т.д.? Intérêt/interest в одном из значений - это прибыль к капиталу (английское interest rate, французское taux d'intérêt).  Поэтому "в интересном положении" - в том положении, когда вероятна "прибыль".  Если речь идёт о молодой женщине, то можно понять, какая прибыль имеется в виду.

Comment: Как же англичане теперь выражают радость, коль скоро такое нужное слово устарело?

Answer (score 0):

> > как по одному этому фразеологизму понятно было бы, о чём речь?

Что тут такого... Таковы все эвфемизмы. Более того, таковы вообще все фразеологизмы. Мы их понимаем, потому что владеем русским языком.

Comment: Мы понимаем слова «положение» и «беременность» как разные. Это не синонимы. Положение — по отдельности и в с другими словами: вне игры, среднее, вертикальное, во гроб, положение как параграф, — что имеет общего с беременностью? Вот мы понимаем язык, но между пониманием и владением, например, хоть и великая разница, но одно из другого как-то вытекает. Как «положение» вытекает из беременности?

Comment: А как наступивший на ухо медведь вытекает из отсутствия слуха? Почему, допустим, медведь, а не, например, слон или конь? Как мы понимаем?

Comment: Наличие уха — предпосылка наличия слуха.